# "Unable to read memory" When using "FILE* file" (C++) on WindowPhone8

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

i got problem when using "FILE* file;" with C++ on WP8.
My app crash when meet the line above.
When i debug, i saw:

```
 1. All the member of this variable "file" got message:
    (file)->_ptr: Unable to read memory.
    (file)->_cnt: Unable to read memory.
    (file)->_base: Unable to read memory.
    (file)->_flag: Unable to read memory.
    (file)->_file: Unable to read memory.
    (file)->_charbuf: Unable to read memory.
    (file)->_tmpfname: Unable to read memory.
    (file)->_bufsiz: Unable to read memory.
```

I have no idea to fix it.

And this is the code i Use:

```
void SubMenu::LoadConfig(float dt)
{
    TiXmlDocument doc;
    bool flag = doc.LoadFile("Config\Config.xml");// Error here.
    TiXmlElement* root = doc.FirstChildElement();
    for (TiXmlElement* elem = root->FirstChildElement(); elem != NULL; elem = elem->NextSiblingElement())
    {
        std::string elemName = elem->Value();
        int Star = atoi(elem->GetText());
        if (elemName == "Tractor")
        {
            this->AddStarPoint(Level1, 4, Star);
        }
        if (elemName == "EggsCatch")
        {
            this->AddStarPoint(Level2, 3, Star);
        }
        if (elemName == "EggsCatch2")
        {
            this->AddStarPoint(Level3, 4, Star);
        }
    }
}
```

This is tinyxml.cpp got function LoadFile:

```
bool TiXmlDocument::LoadFile( const char* _filename, TiXmlEncoding encoding )
{
    TIXML_STRING filename( _filename );
    value = filename;

    // reading in binary mode so that tinyxml can normalize the EOL
    FILE* file = TiXmlFOpen( value.c_str (), "rb" ); // Error here. 

    if ( file )
    {
        bool result = LoadFile( file, encoding );
        fclose( file );
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        SetError( TIXML_ERROR_OPENING_FILE, 0, 0, TIXML_ENCODING_UNKNOWN );
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the related code?

Comment: i Use TinyXML to read and write XML file in my Game. And i got this error deep inside the function of TinyXML. You can get TinyXML from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/. then you can open tinyxml.cpp at line 42 where i got this error.

Comment: That is not helping, we need to know how you get there. At first glance, `file` is just not initialized properly, `fopen()` probably returned an error and it is still trying to read from it.

Comment: I already edit My post. Is this have enough information? this is the first time i post. sorry guys if i make mistake.

Comment: Why are you calling LoadFile recursively?  `bool result = LoadFile( file, encoding );`  Or is that a different `LoadFile`?

Comment: this is the different `LoadFile` of the TinyXML. Cant call like this `bool result = LoadFile( file, encoding );`

Comment: As far as I know, WP8 and WinRT only support asynchronous file functions. All CRT memory and file I/O functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `file == NULL` because of a single backslash `\` in the path. Try

- (simpler) replacing it with a slash `"Config/Config.xml"`, or
- (better) escape it with another backslash `"Config\\Config.xml"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it not working.I do not know my device got problem or not, because when i run TinyXML on Win32 -> it run ok, when port to WP8 -> got this problem.